# Correct tense - will/would?

Tags: grammar

which one of the following statement is correct:

I was informed that I will be joining this team 
(or)
I was informed that I would be joining this team.

FYI: I am joining the team next week, and I am updating my teammate about this.

Comment: Both are fine.  To me, *would* sounds slightly more distant and may have a slightly stronger connotation that joining the team wasn't your choice.

Comment: To me only the second is grammatical. I would say either *I've been informed that I'll be joining this team* or *I was informed that I'd be joining this team.*

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be verified in this [Grammarly article](http://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/1043-will-vs-would/).

Since you are joining the team next week, then "will" is the answer you seek. 
Although "would" is proper because it is the past tense of will and you are relating information that already has happened. "Would" also implies the word "could" however, and since in the context you have presented, you said that it is an affirmative that you are joining, then will works best.

Comment: I'm almost sure this is a duplicate, but the article you link to seems clearer than most. However, 'would' has many flavours (see Nathaniel's comment) and may be the preferred choice here in some contexts.